# Are there data sources for high fidelity cloud cover data?

Tags: weather, weather-api

Is there anything near the resolution of Himawari-8 for the entire globe?

The only one I know of is http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=MODAL2_D_CLD_FR&date=2016-01-01 however there are missing stripes and the granularity is on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the globally data for cloud coverage? Himawari-8 is geostationary satellite. So it is able to observe continuously every 10 min for fulldisk area. But only cover one part of earth.

So if you want cloud coverage product for globally from geostationary satellite, you may look for the combined data from several geo-satellite. Like Geos-R (US), MSG (europe), Himawari-8 (japan), etc.

Previously there was CLAUS data, developed by BADC in UK. But the data (I guess) only until 2008...(need to check)

Hope it might help.